# CCACHE_LOGFILE not written in Github workflow

Tags: github-actions, ccache

I have enabled `ccache` in my Github workflow. Surprisingly and differently from what happens when I build the library on my local machine where I get a hit rate of 100%, during Github build I am getting a hit rate of 30%. Therefore I wanted to enable the `CCACHE_LOGFILE` functionality in order to investigate the reason for this low hit rate. Please note that I have `ccache` enabled for Linux, Macos and Windows builds. Let's take as example only the Linux build. The same issue is happening for all the other builds.

In my Github workflow file I have the following action to set `ccache` environment variables:

```yaml
- name: CCache Configure
  if: matrix.settings.os != 'windows-latest'
  id: ccache-config-linux
  shell: bash
  run: |
    source build/generators/conanbuild.sh
    mkdir $HOME/.ccache
    export CCACHE_DIR=$HOME/.ccache
    export CCACHE_SLOPPINESS=pch_defines,time_macros
    export CCACHE_NOHASHDIR=1
    export CCACHE_LOGFILE=$HOME/.ccache/CcacheLogFile.log
    #export CCACHE_RECACHE=1
    echo "CCACHE_HOME=$HOME/.ccache" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    ccache -p
```

And then the following action to show the results of the `ccache` build process and to show the content of the log file:

```yaml
- name: CCache Stats
  if: matrix.settings.os != 'windows-latest'
  shell: bash
  run: |
      source build/generators/conanbuild.sh
      ccache -d $HOME/.ccache -svvz
      ls -la $HOME/.ccache
      cat $HOME/.ccache/CcacheLogFile.log
      rm $HOME/.ccache/CcacheLogFile.log
      ls -la $HOME/.ccache
```

Surprise surprise... The file `CcacheLogFile.log` is empty! As it can be seen from the command output `cat $HOME/.ccache/CcacheLogFile.log`

```bash
total 76
drwxr-xr-x 19 runner docker 4096 Nov  3 22:55 .
drwxr-x--- 17 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 0
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 1
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 2
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 3
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 4
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 5
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 6
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 7
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 8
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 9
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker    0 Nov  3 23:53 CcacheLogFile.log
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 a
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 b
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 c
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 d
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 e
drwxr-xr-x 18 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:51 f
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4096 Nov  4 08:50 lock
```

So... Not sure what's going wrong here. When I enable the `CCACHE_LOGFILE` in my local machine build everything goes smoothly.
Has anyone faced the same issue before?
Any advice is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Isn't [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) supposed to help in recompilation and not on the first run? On your local machine, its cache keeps updating with each re/compilations that's why you see cache hits. Whereas each new GHA workflow run is a new machine i.e. the cache by ccache isn't being saved/restored between different workflow runs. So, you need to use it in combination with https://github.com/actions/cache. Check https://github.com/hendrikmuhs/ccache-action which seems to be doing this already.